# Angular2 build - Refreshing with valid sub urls shows servers 404 page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular2(With typescript) is build and whenever trying to refresh with valid suburl, it shows server's 404 page. But in the non builded versions it is working fine.

Is there anything want to do extra to get this work.

Suppose my domain is : http://localhost
and suppose I reached here: suburl: http://localhost/users
and if I am refreshing the page, it show servers 404 page (Shows the server - apache or ngnix corresponding 404 page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `HashLocationStrategy`

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make refreshing and navigation work correctly with the default PathLocationStrategy, you must configure your server to forward http://localhost/users to http://localhost/index.html. How to do this depends on what server you are using.

Comment: any idea about how to setup on JBOSS server?